# How do I catch a form submit in Javascript onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, onload

I have a 3rd party system, where I can add articles (with (raw) html). One page contains a search form, which does a post to itself. Upon load (after post) it will add a javascript submit form using javascript - e.g.

```
function redir() {
   document.myform.submit();
}
.... //some other stuff here
redir();
```

I'll not go into details on the design (I know why it is designed this way but cannot change it - its crappy design, I know!).

Is there someway to catch this "onload" submit?

I have tried this:

```
var sform = document.getElementsByName('myform');
try {
    sform.addEventListener("submit", alert('Gotcha!'));
} catch(e) {
    sform.attachEvent("submit", alert('Gotcha!')); //Internet Explorer
}
```

Also jQuery:

```
$('myform').submit(function() {
    alert('Gotcha!');
    return false;
});
```

I cannot seem to catch the event. I can override the method:

```
redir = function(){
    //Empty - override
}
```

...but the submit action is trigged before my script is loaded or it will override my overridding method.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery was close. You just need to use a # before your id based selector, just like in CSS.

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    alert('Gotcha!');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't the form need `id="myform"` for this solution? Also can you demo this, as I can't get it working.

Comment: I don't have an id, but... dooh, of course I need to select the correct form. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @andyb I made an educated guess that his form had an id since he was referring to it as document.myform. I missed the getElementByName call he was making.

Answer (score 0):

Did you override the function in the correct place? The following works for me and stops the submit.

```
function redir() {
    document.myform.submit();
}

redir = function(){}

redir();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XR76h/)

Comment: I can only add an article above or below the script/form so this will not work for me...

Comment: Actually, even putting `redir = function(){}` before the `function redir()` stops the submit.